# Why does using numeric.toString() as an array key cause my script to get stuck

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've found myself doing something like:

```
function populateDueJob (unixTimeStamp, valueToPush) {
  // note: this is a nested function so dueJobs is declared outside.
  // it's declared as: let dueJobs = []
  unixTimeStamp = unixTimeStamp.toString()
  if (dueJobs.indexOf(unixTimeStamp) === -1) {
    dueJobs.push(unixTimeStamp)
    dueJobs[unixTimeStamp] = []
  }

  dueJobs[unixTimeStamp].push(valueToPush)
}
```

This allows me to have a unix time stamp and get all the jobs due simply by using an index lookup. What I've found though is that even though I'm calling `toString()` the index is converted (?) / treated as an int and it causes my scripts to get stuck (I'm not 100% sure how, it just doesn't complete and causes chrome to show the stuck script dialogue).

To fix this, I've done `unixTimeStamp = 'idx_' + unixTimeStamp`. This isn't a problem but I'd like to understand this behavior and if I should be doing something different?

Comment: How is `dueJobs` being initialized? Can you provide an MCVE?

Comment: it looks as dueJobs is an array. (the push seems superfluous?). If you make dueJobs an object instead, the indexer should be treated as a string (property)

Comment: @Me.Name nailed exactly what I was getting at.

Comment: Ah. Correct, `let dueJobs = []` is what I have. Didn't think of using an object. I'll modify the code. Could you post an answer?

Comment: Okidoki, made a post from it with a short example (seemed so short otherwise :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dueJobs` is an array, the index setter `[]` will treat the argument as an integer if possible (the first push onto dueJobs seems unneeded). If turned into an object, the property can be treated as a string

```js
var arr=  ['a'], obj = {0:'a'},prop = '1'; 

arr[prop] = 'b';
console.log(arr);

obj[prop] = 'b';
console.log(obj);
```

But if ES6 is allowed (seems to be, since a `let` is used), a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) could be used as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, you're right the first push wasn't required.